# Unix comparing more than 2 files

Tags: unix

I got four files I need to compare, and I want the output to display the numbers in file X that are not present in the other files.

The files consist of one column, where on each row we have a number.
Example:
File 1 ( 1 2 3 )
File 2 ( 1 2 3 )
File 3 ( 1 2 3 )
File 4 ( 1 2 )
We need the output to show that 3 is missing. So the output will be 3.

I can't use the `diff` command because it is not available.

I was trying to use `comm`, but the output was wrong every time.

Comment: @konsolebox what do u mean?

Comment: We have to have actual data to process and expected output in order to help you.

Comment: Oh okey

Consider we have the following:

File 1 ( 1 2 3 ) File 2 ( 1 2 3 ) File 3 ( 1 2 3 ) File 4 (1 2 )

We need the output to show that 3 is missing. So the output will be 3.

Comment: I wrote a [program](https://github.com/nibrahim/lines) that allows you to treat lines in a file like members of a set. You can use it to do this. Concatenate files 2, 3 and 4 and then use lines to find the difference between 1 and the newly created file.

Comment: it already worked with me, thank you @NoufalIbrahim

Comment: Somebody clarify whether *missing from any other file* or *missing from all other files* (*missing from union*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider we have 3 files N1 N2 N3 to compare.

Add all the values in the files in a new one called out, duplicates removed.
Then compare each file with the main one "out" and output Missing for each comparison.
Then add the missing values in one file, sort them and remove duplicates.

```bash
sort -u N1 N2 N3 > out
sort N1 | comm -2 -3 out > Missing1
sort N2 | comm -2 -3 out > Missing2
sort N3 | comm -2 -3 out > Missing3
sort -u Missing1 Missing2 Missing3 > Missing.txt
```

Comment: This seems to solve a different problem: no fourth file, *not common to all files*.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an easy task actually. You can try this. It uses GNU awk.

```
gawk 'function report() { printf("File \"%s\" has different number of lines: %d\nIt should be %d\n", FILENAME, FNR, o); exit } NR == FNR { a[NR] = $0; ++o; next } FNR > o { report() } a[FNR] != $0 { printf("Line %d of file \"%s\" is different from line in file \"%s\": %s\nIt should be: %s\n", FNR, FILENAME, ARGV[1], $0, a[FNR]); exit } ENDFILE { if (ARGIND > 1 && FNR != o) report() }' file1 file2 file3
```

Script version:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
function report() {
    printf("File \"%s\" has different number of lines: %d\nIt should be %d\n",
        FILENAME, FNR, o)
    exit 1
}
NR == FNR { 
    a[NR] = $0
    ++o
    next
}
FNR > o {
    report()
}
a[FNR] != $0 {
    printf("Line %d of file \"%s\" is different from line in file \"%s\": %s\nIt should be: %s\n",
        FNR, FILENAME, ARGV[1], $0, a[FNR])
    exit 1
}
ENDFILE {
    if (ARGIND > 1 && FNR != o)
        report()
}
```

Usage:

```
gawk -f script.awk file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Comment: Hey

I could not try this because i have a problem with cygwin and scripts on windows.

I found another solution that works kinda good for a low amount of files to compare

Comment: @Necro1992 It's ok. I just tried to deliver an example :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have vim installed then issue this command

```
vim -d file1 file2 file3 ...
```